# SQLAlchemy abstract class relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my app I want to make following hierarchy:

```
class BaseCadastralObject(Base):
    abstract__ = True

    cadastral_region = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_district = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_object = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

These fields combine a primary key.

A have a child classes, for example:

```
class Building(BaseCadastralObject):
    __tablename__ == 'buildings'
    ...
class Construction(BaseCadastralObject):
    __tablename__ == 'constructions'
    ...
```

I also have a table which should be related to those objects like this (many to many):

```
class Parameter(Base):

    __tablename__ == 'parameters'
    parent_cadastral_region = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_district = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_object = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    parent_building = relationship(BaseCadastralObject, backref='parameters')
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
        [parent_cadastral_region, parent_cadastral_district, parent_cadastral_object],
        [BaseCadastralObject.cadastral_region, BaseCadastralObject.cadastral_district, BaseCadastralObject.cadastral_object]),
                  {}
)
```

And I should be able to do following:

```
b = Building(...)
parameters = b.parameters
```

But I'm getting different errors for example this one:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'app.models.BaseCadastralObject' is not mapped
```

Comment: what is the difference between `Building` and `Construction`?

Comment: Is `__tablename__ == 'buildings'` from your actual code? Unless you've defined the name `__tablename__` in global scope, you should be getting `NameError`. All in all this code contains multiple small errors that make this unverifiable.

Comment: You can't have a relationship to an abstract class. What you're looking for is [concrete table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#relationships-with-concrete-inheritance).

Comment: I've recreated a fuller question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972912/abstract-table-concrete-inheritance-could-not-determine-join-condition-between)