# Abstract Table Concrete Inheritance. Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've got following example code:

models.py

```
class CadastralObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cadastral_object'
    def __init__(self, cadastral_region, cadastral_district, cadastral_block, cadastral_object):
        self.cadastral_region = cadastral_region
        self.cadastral_district = cadastral_district
        self.cadastral_block = cadastral_block
        self.cadastral_object = cadastral_object

    # this is a combined PK
    cadastral_region = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_district = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_block = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_object = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    encumbrances = relationship("Encumbrance")

class Encumbrance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'encumbrance'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    def __init__(self, cadastral_object):
        self.parent_cadastral_region = cadastral_object.cadastral_region
        self.parent_cadastral_district = cadastral_object.cadastral_district
        self.parent_cadastral_block = cadastral_object.cadastral_block
        self.parent_cadastral_object = cadastral_object.cadastral_object

    # FK fields
    parent_cadastral_region = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_district = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_block = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_object = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    parent_object = relationship(CadastralObject)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
        [
            parent_cadastral_region,
            parent_cadastral_district,
            parent_cadastral_block,
            parent_cadastral_object],
        [
            CadastralObject.cadastral_region,
            CadastralObject.cadastral_district,
            CadastralObject.cadastral_block,
            CadastralObject.cadastral_object]),
                      {}
    )
```

this code works as intended:

main.py

```
c = CadastralObject(1, 2, 3, 4)
session.add(c)
e = Encumbrance(c)
session.add(e)
session.commit()
print(c.encumbrances)
print(e.parent_object)
```

results:

```
[<app.models.Encumbrance object at 0x000001C9B820BCC0>]
<app.models.CadastralObject object at 0x000001C9B820BB00>
```

however, when I'm trying convert my code to Concrete Inheritance:

imodels.py

```
class iCadastralObject(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):

    def __init__(self, cadastral_region, cadastral_district, cadastral_block, cadastral_object):
        self.cadastral_region = cadastral_region
        self.cadastral_district = cadastral_district
        self.cadastral_block = cadastral_block
        self.cadastral_object = cadastral_object

    # this is a combined PK
    cadastral_region = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_district = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_block = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cadastral_object = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    @declared_attr
    def encumbrances(self):
        return relationship("iEncumbrance")


class Building(iCadastralObject):
    __tablename__ = 'building'

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'building',
        'concrete': True
    }

    @declared_attr
    def encumbrances(self):
        return relationship("iEncumbrance")


class Flat(iCadastralObject):
    __tablename__ = 'flat'

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'flat',
        'concrete': True
    }

    @declared_attr
    def encumbrances(self):
        return relationship("iEncumbrance")


class Construction(iCadastralObject):
    __tablename__ = 'construction'

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'construction',
        'concrete': True
    }


class iEncumbrance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'iencumbrance'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    def __init__(self, cadastral_object):
        self.parent_cadastral_region = cadastral_object.cadastral_region
        self.parent_cadastral_district = cadastral_object.cadastral_district
        self.parent_cadastral_block = cadastral_object.cadastral_block
        self.parent_cadastral_object = cadastral_object.cadastral_object

    # FK fields
    parent_cadastral_region = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_district = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_block = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_cadastral_object = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    parent_object = relationship(iCadastralObject)

    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
        [
            parent_cadastral_region,
            parent_cadastral_district,
            parent_cadastral_block,
            parent_cadastral_object],
        [
            iCadastralObject.cadastral_region,
            iCadastralObject.cadastral_district,
            iCadastralObject.cadastral_block,
            iCadastralObject.cadastral_object]),
                      {}
    )
```

I'm getting an error on "from app.imodels import Building"

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship iCadastralObject.encumbrances - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Comment: i don't understand when people try to use inheritance in ORM, while tables themselves are don't share data or structure – they are independent AFAIK, so why to try make models inheritance when in fact there is no inheritance in database?

Comment: is it crucial for you to have inheritance or you just avoiding boilerplate? or is it a research of `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but there will be a lot of similar objects with similar data and small differences. Trying to avoid a lot of code duplication.